# Fastlane does not email my internal testers for testflight

Tags: ios, testflight, fastlane

For the life of me I can't find out info to get my app store upload to email/notify my testers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what's in my FastFile.

```
lane :deploytest do
gym(scheme: "Target_AppStore") # Build your app - more options available

# fixes firewall issue
ENV["DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS"] = "-t DAV"
pilot(
    #You can also skip the submission of the binary, which means, the ipa file will only be uploaded and not distributed to testers:
    skip_submission: false,
)

# sh "your_script.sh"
# You can also use other beta testing services here (run `fastlane actions`)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot

```
pilot(
  #You can also skip the submission of the binary, which means, the ipa file will only be uploaded and not distributed to testers:
  skip_submission: false,
  distribute_external: false, #this needed to be added for internal builds
)
```